# itextsharp set bookmarks to fit page

Tags: itext

I'm starting out with itextsharp and I've managed to answer all my questions but one:
How are bookmarks set to open to the fitpage zoom/view?

I apologize if this has already been answered elsewhere.
Here's my code if it helps.

*//edit: Below is my working code. It has been modified using Bruno's example.*

```
 Public Sub MergePDFFiles(FileList As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of ModifiedItemForList), pdfName As String, pageCount As Integer)

    Dim reader As PdfReader
    Dim mergedPdf As Byte() = Nothing
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim page As Integer
    Dim par As Paragraph
    Dim pageMode As Integer
    Dim pageLayout As Integer
    Dim pageZoom As PdfDestination
    Dim outlineZoom As PdfDestination
    Dim pdfAction As PdfAction
    Dim root As PdfOutline
    Dim pdfOutline As PdfOutline

    Using ms As New MemoryStream()

        Using document As New Document()

            Using copy As New PdfCopy(document, ms)
                'Dim copy As New PdfCopy(document, ms)
                document.Open()
                root = copy.RootOutline
                pageMode = copy.PageModeUseOutlines
                pageLayout = copy.PageLayoutSinglePage
                pageZoom = New PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT)
                copy.ViewerPreferences = pageMode
                pdfAction = pdfAction.GotoLocalPage(1, pageZoom, copy)
                copy.SetOpenAction(pdfAction)

                ' For Each FilePath As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In FileList  ' .Count - 1
                For i As Integer = 0 To pageCount - 1
                    ' FilePath As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
                    If File.Exists(FileList.Item(i).Value) Then
                        reader = New PdfReader(FileList.Item(i).Value)
                        ' loop over the pages in that document
                        n = reader.NumberOfPages
                        page = 0
                        par = New Paragraph(FileList.Item(i).Key)
                        Debug.Print("FileList.Item(i).Key = " & FileList.Item(i).Key)
                        outlineZoom = New PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT)
                        pdfOutline = New PdfOutline(root, outlineZoom, par)

                        While page < n
                            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(page)))
                        End While

                    End If

                Next

            End Using

        End Using

        mergedPdf = ms.ToArray()

    End Using

    File.WriteAllBytes(pdfName, mergedPdf)

End Sub
```

Your input will be greatly appreciated,
Corbin de Bruin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want custom bookmarks, please don't use `Chapter` and `Section`, use `PdfOutline` instead. This is (of course) documented in [chapter 7](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=7) of my [book](http://itextpdf.com/book/). If you need the C# port of the examples, take a look at the [code examples for chapter 7](https://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/itextsharp/ci/32f5ab36f74e8ffafcd47ef1649a56d7a453ad19/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter07), specifically [CreateOutlineTree.cs](https://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/itextsharp/ci/32f5ab36f74e8ffafcd47ef1649a56d7a453ad19/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter07/CreateOutlineTree.cs), where instead of using `PdfDestination.FITH` (for Fit Horizontally) and a Y position, you just create a destination with `PdfDestination.FIT` (and no extra parameter):

```
new PdfOutline(root, new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT), title, true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Bruno. I posted modifications to my code above to fit the your example and suggestion.